# Java equivalent of Ruby AES CBC Decryption

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, aes

The below ruby code works

```
require 'openssl'
require "base64"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)   
cipher.decrypt   
cipher.key = Base64.strict_decode64("LLkRRMSAlD16lrfbRLdIELdj0U1+Uiap0ihQrRz7HSQ=")    
cipher.iv = Base64.strict_decode64("A23OFOSvsC4UyejA227d8g==")
crypt = cipher.update(Base64.strict_decode64("D/e0UjAwBF+d8aVqZ0FpXA=="))    
crypt << cipher.final
puts crypt # prints Test123
```

but trying to do the same in java with same key/iv/cipher but it doesn't return 'Test123'

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode("LLkRRMSAlD16lrfbRLdIELdj0U1+Uiap0ihQrRz7HSQ=");
    byte[] iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode("A23OFOSvsC4UyejA227d8g==");
    byte[] input = Base64.getDecoder().decode("D/e0UjAwBF+d8aVqZ0FpXA==");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(input);
    System.out.println("[" + new String(output) + "] - "+output.length);
```

For simplicity key and iv are hardcoded

Comment: `cipher.decrypt` does not translate to `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`

Comment: @zapl. Thanks. Silly me. With 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding' leading space got truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling it to encrypt, not to decrypt. The corrected line of code is

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

Furthermore, if you want to use BouncyCastle for this, use

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

or make BouncyCastle the default:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```